# How to compare generic types?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class which has some properties of type `List<float>`, `List<int>` etc. Now I am quering the properties of this class through reflection so that I get a list of `PropertyInfo`.

I want to filter the types which are of type `List<>`. But the comparison

```
propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(List<>)
```

fails.

I can get around this by comparing the names, i.e., the following comparison works:

```
propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name == typeof(List<>).Name
```

I think there should be a better way to compare the Generic types. Any clues?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use:

```
Type type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    ...
}
```